# Under what condition on f is this parametrized curve regular?

Tags: trigonometry, differential-geometry

Consider a parametrized curve in $\mathbb R^2$ given by 
$$ \gamma (t)=(f(t)\cos(t), f(t)\sin(t)) $$
where $f$ is a smooth function of $t$. Under what condition on $f$ is $\gamma$ regular?

I took the derivative and got 
 $$ \gamma' (t)=(f'(t)\cos(t)-f(t)\sin(t), f'(t)\sin(t)+f(t)\cos(t)) $$
I tried to find functions for $f(t)$ that would make $\gamma (t)=(0,0)$, but I could not find any such functions. I then took the second and third derivatives to try and find functions that would make them $(0,0)$. I really don't know what else to do, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the post? If you leave it then maybe someone else will benefit from your question.

Comment: You shouldn't delete your question. There wasn't anything wrong with it, and it might be useful for someone in the future. I'm itching to rollback to the question :P

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $\gamma' \equiv 0 \iff \| \gamma'(t) \| = 0 \ \forall t$, that is, $\langle \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle  = 0 \ \forall t$. We have: $$\langle \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle = (f'(t) \cos t)^2 - 2 f'(t)f(t) \cos t \sin t + (f(t) \sin t)^2 + (f'(t) \sin t)^2 + 2f'(t)f(t)\cos t \sin t + (f(t) \cos t)^2$$
which happily simplifies to: $$\langle \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle = (f'(t))^2 + (f(t))^2$$
But this is identically zero only when $f' \equiv 0$ and $f \equiv 0$. So, if you want $\gamma$ to be regular, the above situation can **not** happen.